# How can Gradle resolve a test jar in the maven repository?

Tags: maven, testing, gradle, jar

So we had a portion of our build that was dog slow because it had a lot of drules compilation in it. A custom maven plug-in was written for that but while converting to Gradle, it was decided to extract this portion to another project and later there would be a drules upgrade that uses the new plug-in they provide.

That decision left us with some project dependencies that became jar dependencies like this one. This is necessary because, someone decided used some classes from one subproject, in another:

```
testCompile "com.someplace:xyz-somedata:4.4.0-SNAPSHOT-tests"
```

Problem is that this does not resolve despite the fact that I've verified that it is in the local repo.

...OK. I was able to get this to resolve by re-installing it into the local repo using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=${2} -DgroupId=${GROUP} -DartifactId=${NAME} -Dversion=${VERSION} -Dpackaging=jar
```

...such that it is now in:

```
4.4.0-SNAPSHOT-tests/xyz-somedata-4.4.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar.
```

as opposed to

```
6.6.0-SNAPSHOT/wnp-participantdata-6.6.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
```

In a nutshell, this makes it a production jar while the other one is a test jar.

Isn't there a better solution? Hacks like this just leave a bad taste in my mouth. Shouldn't I be able to tell Gradle in some manner that this is a test jar and that is where it will be found in the repo? Gradle should be able to do this, IMHO, if it fully supports maven. Possible bug?

Comment: Is your question about [Dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html), specifically managing jars for test configurations?

Comment: use `tests` as a classifier, which it is, instead of appending it to the version.

Comment: I guess it is a good thing that you're providing context, but your question is difficult to read and sort of detracts from the actual question

Comment: That happens when you are not quite sure what the question you are asking is. ;-) Re-phrase as answer and I'll give it to you. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as:

```
testCompile "com.someplace:xyz-somedata:4.4.0-SNAPSHOT:tests"
```

Gradle dependency declaration takes the form:

```
[organisation]:[module]:[revision]:[classifier]@[ext]
```